# Break line within the same WhatsApp message using PyWhatKit.sendwhatmsg_to_group

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to send a message to a group using [PyWhatKit](https://pypi.org/project/pywhatkit/)'s `sendwhatmsg_to_group` but have not found a reliable way of breaking the line inside the message (a `Shift+Enter` operation), so that the resulting sent message is something like:

```
Hello
World
```

instead of Hello and World being separate messages. I tried using `\r\n`,  `\n`, no luck.